# ReadConsoleOutputCharacter error using second parameter

Tags: c, winapi

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684969(v=vs.85).aspx
error C2664: 'ReadConsoleOutputCharacterW' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'char *' to 'LPWSTR'

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    HANDLE hOut;
    char letter;
    char letters[5];
    DWORD numberRead;
    COORD where_;

    SetConsoleTitle(L"Hello!");
    hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    where_.X = 0;
    where_.Y = 0;
    ReadConsoleOutputCharacter(hOut, &letter, 1, where_, &numberRead);
    printf("letter at (0,0) is %c letter", letter);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are compiling with unicode support enabled (because `ReadConsoleOutputCharacter` resolves to `ReadConsoleOutputCharacterW`, otherwise it would resolve to `ReadConsoleOutputCharacterA`).

This means all strings and characters used with any WinAPI functions need to be wide characters `WCHAR` instead of `char` and `LPWSTR` instead of `LPSTR`, .... Or you disable unicode by undefining the appropriate preprocessor symbols (`UNICODE` and `_UNICODE`, I think). But in this case your `SetConsoleTitle` call won't work anymore, as you explicitly pass it a wide string.

But the most flexible would be to use `TCHAR` instead of `char` and `LPTSTR` instead of `LPSTR` and the like. These are just defined to the correct types depending on the definition of the `UNICODE` preprocessor symbol. In this case the code stays widely independent of unicode support. But in this case you have to wrap all string literals in the `_T`, `T` or `TEXT` macro:

```
//non-unicode
const char *str = "something";

//unicode
const WCHAR *str = L"something";

//unicode-agnostic
const TCHAR *str = _T("something");
```

See [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Programming/Unicode) for an introduction to the problem.

If you don't really need unicode support and only need some simple WinAPI functions and want them to interface well with the C standard library (like in your case it seems), it would be the best idea to just undefine `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` and use standard `char`s. In this case also remove the `L` modifier from your string literals.